# react react-jsonschema-form update state

Tags: forms, reactjs, jsonschema

I have this form using the [react-jsonschema-form](https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form), the form will receive the enum array from props on `componentWillReceiveProps` and should update the schema that is in the state. But even though I update the state and the schema the form get updated.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/robertosousa/vcL27z58/3/) it's a fiddle with my problem. Basically, the enum should take the value of `[one, two]` on click.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the object assigns to the state doesn't work very well. The best way to do it (that worked for me) is using the latest Object.assign() method ([here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)).
[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/robertosousa/vcL27z58/4/) it is the updates fiddle with the working solution using

```
this.setState({schema: Object.assign({}, this.state.schema, {
    properties:{list:{enum: ["1", "2"], enumNames: ["Name 1", "Name 2"]}}
})})
```

Comment: worked like charm, dynamic rect schema form update